# Can find RSA private key for uploading my SSL certificate to Google App Engine

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-cloud-platform, https, google-app-engine, google-cloud-shell

Right now I am trying to upload a SSL certificate from GoDaddy so That I am able to enable HTTPS for my custom domain name for the website hosted on the app. Whenever, I try to upload the SSL certificate I am able to use the PEM file that came with the certificate bundle works well enough, but I don't seem to have the RSA private key I can use that came with the bundle. I tried to generate a RSA private key using Open SSL but it didn't seem to generate a key I can add to the app. I just need to if I need to get an RSA private key or is there a work around to this problem?

Comment: If you have lost the private key, some vendors allow you to redownload, read their documentation - I do not work with GoDaddy so I do not know. Otherwise, you will need to find the private key. You will not be able to use an SSL certificate without the private key. Note. The SSL certificate contains the public key. It is not possible to generate the private key from the public key (yet). If this were possible, every website in the world would be broken.

Answer (score 0):

As @JohnHanley mentioned, please refer to [GoDaddy documentation](https://www.godaddy.com/help/wheres-my-private-key-32300) that explains how to find your private key:

> When you generate a CSR to request an SSL certificate, a private key
> is created on your local server.

If the instructions didn't help to find the key, other options would be to [install the SSL certificate manually](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-my-google-app-engine-32074)  or to [rekey your certificate](https://www.godaddy.com/help/rekey-my-certificate-4976).

Comment: Ok, that's fine but I have the CSR and I already rekeyed the certificate. So know I would have to figure out to generate a private key from the CSR from the Google Terminal or whatever.